# Replacing one wordpress site with another

Tags: database, wordpress, server

I am looking for a little advice if possible?

I have created a new wordpress website for a client. It is on separate test server.

The client currently has a wordpress site on his live domain.

My question is how best to go about replacing the current live wordpress site with the new one? Any best practices or procedures I should follow?

My thinking was:

1. Make a copy of current live site and database.
2. Add an 'under construction' index.html page.
3. Remove all current live wordpress site files.
4. Add new wordpress site files along with reference to new database.
5. Finally remove the 'under construction' index.html page.

Does this sound ok to you? Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance for any tips or advice!

Comment: Is their any blog posts, user data, or contact info you worry you might lose in the old website?

Comment: Hey thanks, no, there are no blog posts to concern about

Comment: In that case I think your process is good. I'm not sure if under construction template is necessary, unless the website receives a huge traffic. Just remove the old website and install the new one, which shouldn't take more that 15 mins.

Comment: Thanks Sheedo. Can I ask which way you do it?

Answer (score 0):

The way it is sound good if you are non technical or not comfortable with technical stuffs.

You can user below plugins for same.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/